List of Frequently Asked Questions not present in the FAQ
I'm creating this Meta post where we can include some extra-FAQ about the site. If some new user asks a question answered here, link them to the answer or the question. Why an extra FAQ? This way we add the most important things to the FAQ and here we can post more of them, so the FAQ is not cluttered.
This Meta question is opened so everyone can contribute but please:

Use common sense;
Edit using the same format used by the other answers;
If in doubt, ask a Mod;
Don't delete content without permission (this is meant to avoid destructive decisions);
Post one question per answer.

This is meant as an extra help for the community by the community. 

Alphabetical index:

Why was my question closed?


Why was my question closed?
The reason depends on the question closed. Usually it's explained by the mod that closed the question.
But don't worry: closed questions are not closed forever. They can still be improved, edited, and if they meet the standards again, they can be reopened, either by community votes or by a single mod.
Questions that are closed forever are locked or deleted.
For a better understanding of the closing mechanism, check this guide provided by Ninefingers: 
FAQ — A guide to moderation: Voting to close a question.
